# Download image, save to store, but image gallery cant see that image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save, gallery

I am making gallery app which downloads images from server and puts in app folder. But when i open this app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.album), i cant see my download images. This is my code
download image:

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(path)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "pamti se");
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    saveToDirectory(resource, path);
                                }
                            }, 0);

                        }

                    });
```

save to directory:

```
private void saveToDirectory(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(path);
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Došlo je do greške!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Slika je sačuvana!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Došlo je do greške!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Došlo je do greške!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Nullable
private File getOutputMediaFile(String path) {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name));
    Log.d(TAG, mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath());

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    String name = "";
    for(int i = path.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (path.charAt(i) == '/') {
            break;
        }
        name = path.charAt(i) + name;
    }

    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName = getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name) +"_"+ name;
    //String mImageName = "IMG" +"-"+ name;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving your image to your internal app storage, you need to make it available to the gallery (external storage of your app) in order to be available outside your app.

Try this method:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    //change mCurrentPhotoPath for your imagepath
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Reference to the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

Save your files to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

Step 2.
Use MediaScanner to notify the system about the new file/image. I created a helper class for that. All you have to do is pass in the file path:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class MediaScannerUtils implements
        MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MediaScannerUtils";

    private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
    private @Nullable WeakReference<MediaScannerListener> mListenerRef;
    private String mPathToScan;
    private String mMimeType;

    /**
     * Initialize the MediaScannerUtils class
     * @param context Any context
     * @param listener A listener that gets notified when the scan is completed
     * @param pathToScan The path to scan. If null, the entire sdcard is scanned
     * @param mimeType The mimeType of files to look for. If null, defaults to "audio/*"
     */
    public MediaScannerUtils(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable MediaScannerListener listener,
                             @Nullable String pathToScan, @Nullable String mimeType) {
        LogUtils.d(LOG_TAG, "Initializing MediaScannerUtils");
        mPathToScan = pathToScan;
        mMimeType = mimeType;
        if(pathToScan == null) {
            //If path to scan is null, set path to the entire SdCard
            mPathToScan = FileUtils.getSDCardAbsolutePath();
        }
        if(mimeType == null) {
            //If mime type is null, set mime type to audio wildcard
            mMimeType = "image/*";
        }

        if(listener != null) {
            mListenerRef = new WeakReference<>(listener);
        }

        mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(context.getApplicationContext(), this);
        mConnection.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client when a connection to the
     * MediaScanner service has been established.
     */
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPathToScan, mMimeType);
    }

    /**
     * Called to notify the client when the media scanner has finished
     * scanning a file.
     * @param path the path to the file that has been scanned.
     * @param uri the Uri for the file if the scanning operation succeeded
     * and the file was added to the media database, or null if scanning failed.
     */
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        if(mConnection != null) {
            mConnection.disconnect();
        }

        if(mListenerRef != null) {
            MediaScannerListener listener = mListenerRef.get();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onScanCompleted();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects the MediaScannerConnection and releases any heavy object
     */
    public void release() {
        if (mConnection != null) {
            mConnection.disconnect();
            mConnection = null;
        }
    }

    public interface MediaScannerListener {

        void onScanCompleted();

    }
}
```